# выгрузка отфильтрованных данных Django

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго времени суток. Занимаюсь разработкой приложения на Джанго для изучения веб программирования.

На странице реализована таблица которая выводит значения нужных полей из БД (в том числе связанных моделей), а также передает в шаблон все возможные значения некоторых полей (для возможности выбора поля при фильтрации). Также реализована фильтрация контента по заданным параметрам. К работе вьюхи и фильтра вопросов нет - все работает как и задумано (возможно написано криво, но работает). Но мне нужно реализовать функцию выгрузки предварительно **отфильтрованных** данных в xls и последующий редирект на эту же страницу с сохранением настроек фильтров.

Ниже куски кода:

```
def ozp(request):
    # получение списков данных для меню выбора -------------------
    objectslist = Ozp.objects.all()
    dep = Department.objects.all()
    ceh_list = []
    uchastok_list = []
    year_list = []
    for i in dep:
        if i.ceh in ceh_list:
            pass
        else:
            ceh_list.append(i.ceh)
        if i.uchastok in uchastok_list:
            pass
        else:
            uchastok_list.append(i.uchastok)
    for i in objectslist:
        try:
            year = i.zakrytie_date.year
            if str(year) in year_list:
                pass
            else:
                year_list.append(str(i.zakrytie_date.year))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    # --------------------------------------------------------------
    # получение введенных в фильр данных --------------------------
    if request.GET:
        ceh = request.GET['ceh']
        uchastok = request.GET['uchastok']
        vipolnenie = request.GET['vipolnenie']
        na_vipolnenie = request.GET['na_vipolnenie']
        year_filter = []
        this_month = request.GET['this_month']
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # получение списка выбранных годов----------------------------------------
        for i in year_list:
            q = ''.join(['year_', str(i)])
            try:
                year_filter.append(request.GET[q])
            except KeyError:
                pass
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # фильтрация по объектам сети----------------------------------------------
        filtered_departments = department_filter(ceh, uchastok)[0]
        filtered_by_department = " ".join(department_filter(ceh, uchastok)[1])
        filtered_objects = Object.objects.filter(uchastok__in=filtered_departments)
        filtered_ozp_objects = Ozp.objects.filter(object_name__in=filtered_objects)
    # фильтрация по выполнению -----------------------------------------------------
        if vipolnenie == '1':
            filtered_by_vipolnenie = 'Выполненным'
            filtered_ozp_objects = filtered_ozp_objects.filter(is_done=True)
        elif vipolnenie == '0':
            filtered_by_vipolnenie = 'Невыполненным'
            filtered_ozp_objects = filtered_ozp_objects.filter(is_done=False)
        else:
            filtered_by_vipolnenie = ''
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # фильтрация по поданным на выполннеине ----------------------------------------
        if na_vipolnenie == '1':
            filtered_by_na_vipolnenie = 'Поданным на устранение'
            filtered_podano = Podano_na_vipolnenie.objects.filter(podano=True)
            filtered_ozp_objects = filtered_ozp_objects.filter(podano_na_vipolnenie__in=filtered_podano)
        elif na_vipolnenie == '0':
            filtered_by_na_vipolnenie = 'Не поданным на устранение'
            filtered_podano = Podano_na_vipolnenie.objects.filter(podano=False)
            filtered_ozp_objects = filtered_ozp_objects.filter(podano_na_vipolnenie__in=filtered_podano)
        else:
            filtered_by_na_vipolnenie = ''
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    # фильтрация по году-------------------------------------------------
        if year_filter != year_list:
            filtered_ozp_objects = filtered_ozp_objects.filter(zakrytie_date__year__in=year_filter)
            filtered_by_year = 'По следующим годам ' + ' '.join(year_filter)
        else:
            filtered_by_year = ''
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
    # фильтрация по выполнению в течении месяца--------------------------
        if this_month == 'this_month':
            month = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=30)
            filtered_ozp_objects = filtered_ozp_objects.filter(zakrytie_date__lt=month)
            filtered_by_month = 'По необходимости выполнения в течении месяца'
        else:
            filtered_by_month = ''
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------
        filtered_by = ' '.join([filtered_by_department, filtered_by_vipolnenie, filtered_by_na_vipolnenie,
                                filtered_by_year, filtered_by_month])
        context = {'objectlist': filtered_ozp_objects, 'ceh': ceh_list, 'uchastok': uchastok_list, 'year': year_list,
                   'filtered_by': filtered_by}
        print(filtered_by)
        return render(request, "main/templates/ozp.html", context)
    else:
        filtered_ozp_objects = Ozp.objects.all()
        filtered_by = str('')
        context = {'objectlist': filtered_ozp_objects, 'ceh': ceh_list, 'uchastok': uchastok_list, 'year': year_list,
                   'filtered_by': filtered_by}
        print(filtered_by)
        return render(request, "main/templates/ozp.html", context)
```

Данная вьюха возвращает в шаблон настройки фильтров, данные для менюшек выбора, строку с указанием по каким параметром выставлены фильтры, и сами данные (объекты).
Фильтрацию по полям связанной таблицы вынес в отдельную функцию:

```
def department_filter(ceh, uchastok):
    filtered_by = []
    if ceh == 'all' and uchastok == 'all':
        filtered_department = Department.objects.all()
    elif ceh == 'all' and uchastok != 'all':
        filtered_department = Department.objects.filter(uchastok=uchastok)
        filtered_by = [uchastok]
    elif ceh != 'all' and uchastok == 'all':
        filtered_department = Department.objects.filter(ceh=ceh)
        filtered_by = [ceh]
    else:
        filtered_department = Department.objects.filter(Q(ceh=ceh), Q(uchastok=uchastok))
        filtered_by = [uchastok, ceh]
    return filtered_department, filtered_by
```

В шаблоне для экспорта реализована отдельная кнопка:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:export_xls_ozp' filtered_by %}">
    <button type="submit">Выгрузить</button>
</form>
```

Пытаюсь в url передать строку filtered_by но данное решение мне кажется неверным по причине возникновения ошибок в случае отсутствия фильтрации(передачи пустой строки). При этом интуитивно понимаю что мне необходимо в функцию  export_xls_ozp передать состояние адресной строки, но как это сделать не знаю. Интернет по запросу мало что выдает.

Найденная на просторах интернета конструкция работать не хочет:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:export_xls_ozp' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">
    <button type="submit">Выгрузить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется разобрался:

```
<a href="{% url 'main:export_xls_ozp' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">
    <button type="submit">Выгрузить</button>
</a>
```

Конструкция работает как ссылка. Формирует get  запрос к view.export_xls_ozp с параметрами установленного фильтра.
В функции export_xls_ozp мы можем легко достать данные параметры при помощи request.GET по необходимому ключу:

```
def export_xls_ozp(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    ceh = request.GET['ceh']
    uchastok = request.GET['uchastok']
    vipolnenie = request.GET['vipolnenie']
    na_vipolnenie = request.GET['na_vipolnenie']
```